# How load some default data to a database

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-room

I followed this tutorial https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view-kotlin/#0 to create a Sqlite DB using Room and couroutines. Everything work fine, but I'm not able (and I don't understand why) to create a default data in my application. Here below my code

```
@Database(entities = [Challenge::class, ChallengeDay::class], version = 1)
abstract class MyDB: RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun challengeDao(): ChallengeDao
    abstract fun challengeDayDao(): ChallengeDayDao

    companion object {

        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: MyDB? = null

        fun getDatabase(ctx: Context, scope: CoroutineScope): MyDB {
            return INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
                val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(ctx.applicationContext, MyDB::class.java, "MY_DATABASE").addCallback(MyDBCallback(scope)).build()

                INSTANCE = instance

                instance
            }
        }

        private class MyDBCallback(private val scope: CoroutineScope): RoomDatabase.Callback() {
            override fun onOpen(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                super.onOpen(db)
                INSTANCE?.let { database ->
                    scope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                        populateDatabase(database.challengeDao(), database.challengeDayDao())
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        suspend fun populateDatabase(challengeDao: ChallengeDao, challengeDayDao: ChallengeDayDao) {

            val standardChallenge = Challenge(name = "Standard challenge", standard = true)
            val id = challengeDao.insert(standardChallenge)

            challengeDayDao.insert(ChallengeDay(numberOfDay = 1, done = false, challengeId = id, seconds = 20))
            challengeDayDao.insert(ChallengeDay(numberOfDay = 2, done = false, challengeId = id, seconds = 20))
            challengeDayDao.insert(ChallengeDay(numberOfDay = 3, done = false, challengeId = id, seconds = 30))
            challengeDayDao.insert(ChallengeDay(numberOfDay = 4, done = false, challengeId = id, seconds = 30))
            challengeDayDao.insert(ChallengeDay(numberOfDay = 5, done = false, challengeId = id, seconds = 20))
            challengeDayDao.insert(ChallengeDay(numberOfDay = 6, done = false, challengeId = id, seconds = null))
            challengeDayDao.insert(ChallengeDay(numberOfDay = 7, done = false, challengeId = id, seconds = 45))
            challengeDayDao.insert(ChallengeDay(numberOfDay = 8, done = false, challengeId = id, seconds = 45))
            challengeDayDao.insert(ChallengeDay(numberOfDay = 9, done = false, challengeId = id, seconds = 60))
            challengeDayDao.insert(ChallengeDay(numberOfDay = 10, done = false, challengeId = id, seconds = 60))
        }
    }
}
```

I call the function `getDatabase` from the `ViewModel` class like this

```
class ChallengeViewModel(application: Application): AndroidViewModel(application) {

    private val challengeRepository: ChallengeRepository

    val challenges: LiveData<List<Challenge>>

    init {
        val challengeDao = MyDB.getDatabase(application, viewModelScope).challengeDao()
        challengeRepository = ChallengeRepository(challengeDao)

        challenges = challengeRepository.allChallenges
    }
}
```

I noticed that the first time I run the app, the database will be created but it's empty. If I stop the application and then I re-run the database will be populated with default data.

Another doubt. When I write the default data in my db how I can avoid to call `populateDatabase` every time that the app is run?

Thanks to all.

Comment: Sorry for the comment. The default data seem to be created because I see in the RecyclerView, but if I look inside the database it's empty. The second time that I run the application I see the data in database

Comment: I think that the first time that I run the application the data are written (because the second time that I run, opening the database I see the Id = 2 instead of 1) but maybe it's a problem of database refreshing.